# Real-time updating Ant Design table

Tags: c#, reactjs, signalr, antd

I'm running React with Ant Design and ASP.NET Core + SignalR. I'm trying to enable real-time updates to the antd table whenever a new record is inserted, updated, or deleted.

It's not a problem for me to stream the updates from the backend. The issue is that I don't know how to process it in the frontend because the table has pagination and filters.

For instance, let's say a new record was just added -> SignalR sends message to the frontend with the new record -> if we push that item to the state and the user is on page 2, it ain't going to work. In addition, what if there are filters which were applied, and this new record that we got makes no sense to the filtered result?

Let's say a new record was just added and SignalR sent a single message with the new item to the frontend. I can push that new record into the state but what if the user is on page 2? We can't just push it there. What if there are filters that were applied and this new record doesn't correspond to these filters.

Here is the response of the table:

[image]

I also have to highlight the items that have changed. Speaking of it, I was thinking of: what if the server tells the client that something has changed (perhaps a flag or something?) but then how do I refresh the table so that the user remains on the same page and with the same filters applied?

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: @rkrahl, not really. When a new record is inserted or deleted, I'm refreshing the state of the whole table. If there are updates for one of the items, taking into account the pagination, then a push notification is sent to the frontend.